# Can't find a pakage (android)

Tags: android

G'evening. I've installed an app from Google Play Market. Once I discovered that I can find pakages of installed apps in the "Android" folder via "explorer". I have Xiaomi Redmi 7. I checked how the pakage is named (it can be checked in the list of apps at the settings of my smartphone). Then I looked for the pakage in the "Android" folder but didn't find it. I didn't find it when searched by it's name either. I have a question: why can't I find the pakage searching by it's name?

P.S. I use built-in file manager (I named it "explorer")
I use android of "9 PKQ1.181021.001" version

Comment: I think it's because of the latest permission policy by Google. Apps can't read the data or folders of other apps, so these apps need a special permission which I'm not familiar with atm. Files by Google can't read data inside Android folder. Another file explorer asked me to specify the "obb" and "data" folders and it did read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android folder on your virtual SD card which you can see with an unrooted explorer only houses data for some application that require additional external storage.

Most data for most applications is kept under:

```
/data/data/<package.name>
```

Which is a folder you can not view unless you have root permission.

Even ADB is unable to access files in this folder.

If the specific app you are using does not have `allowBackup` flag set to `false` (by the developer), it may be possible to run:

```
adb backup package.name
```

Then unpack the backup file as explained here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/how-do-you-extract-an-apps-data-from-a-full-backup-made-through-adb-backup/78183#78183